continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^*$
I am having a confusion, what I know is that the function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^*}$, since $\mathbb{R^*}$ is its domain.
But when I was discussing this with one of my colleagues that belongs to the French school, he said that we can never say that a function is continuous on $\mathbb{R^*}$, we should say that the function is continuous on all the "intervals" that compose $\mathbb{R^*}$.
Is this difference just because he is from the French school or he is generally right? thank you

The answer depends on the topology you have chosen on $R^*$.

I am only talking about calculus of highschool

$\mathbb{R}^*$, I assumed is some compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, Alexandroff extension. In that case, you can extend the definition of $x\mapsto 1/x$ from $\mathbb{R}{0}$ to $\mathbb{R}\cup {\infty}$. Then, You can check if open sets containing ${\infty}$ have open preimages.

@NorbertBarankai The usual topology on $ℝ^*$ is of course the metric topology (which is the same as the subspace topology induced by the topology on $ℝ$). At the high school level, I doubt this is about compactification…

@JeanAbouSamra I think I had some confusion with the actual meaning of the symbol $\mathbb{R}^{*}$. For me, I thought from the question it was some compactification, nonetheless turned out to be $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ (usually denoted by $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ in the literature I am acquinted with.). Note that, from the original question the meaning of the symbol and the level of difficulty was far from straightforward.

The function $f: ℝ^* ↦ ℝ^*, x ↦ \frac{1}{x}$ is indeed continuous, which you can see by applying the definition (if you've been taught the definition of continuity at the high school level): for all $ε > 0$ and for all $x ∈ ℝ^*$, there is $η > 0$ such that $f$ takes values in $(f(x)-ε, f(x)+ε)$ on $(x-η, x+η)$.
It is possible that your French classmate was only taught about continuity on an interval, but continuity is a more general mathematical concept.

I am sorry , if I understand right, saying that $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^}$ is right or saying that $\dfrac{1}{x}$ is continuous on each interval of $\mathbb{R^}$ is right? I mean, is continuity should only apply on intervals or also on sets that are not connected like $\mathbb{R^*}$?

Yes, saying that $x ↦ \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $ℝ^*$ is perfectly right.
